# The same response type in two requests in MassTransit Saga

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to create a state machine and I'd like to send multiple requests from this state machine. The requests are defined as follows:

```
public Request<StageState, ICloseStage, ICloseStageRequestSuccess, IRequestFailed> CloseStageRequest { get; private set; }

public Request<StageState, IPublishStage, IPublishStageRequestSuccess, IRequestFailed> PublishStageRequest { get; private set; }
```

Both requests might get the same response in `Response2`. However, when I'm running the state machine I'm getting the following error:

System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: IRequestFailed

So, I suppose this is happening because I'm using `IRequestFailed` in both requests. Is it a by-design behavior or is there a workaround so I can use this response type in both requests? I really need to use it in this way because `IRequestFailed` is processed in a unified way for all the requests in the state machine, and I'm planning to add more requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MassTransit state machine does not support two requests with the same response type.